# How to add Shopify webhook and make it works

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I generated new webhook into my app by run `shopify generate webhook`. After that I see this code is created

```
  config.webhooks = [
    {topic: 'checkouts/create', address: 'https://66562fbc5033.ngrok.io/webhooks/checkouts/create', format: 'json'},
    {topic: 'carts/update', address: 'https://66562fbc5033.ngrok.io/webhooks/carts/update', format: 'json'},
    {topic: 'carts/update', address: 'https://66562fbc5033.ngrok.io/webhooks/carts/create', format: 'json'},
    {topic: 'app/uninstalled', address: 'https://66562fbc5033.ngrok.io/webhooks/app/uninstalled', format: 'json'},
  ]
```

Then I goto my shop and add new webhook from Settings -> Notifications -> Create new webhook
But seem it's not working.

This is controller

```
class HomeController < AuthenticatedController
  def index
    @products = ShopifyAPI::Product.find(:all, params: { limit: 10 })
    @webhooks = ShopifyAPI::Webhook.find(:all)
  end
end
```

This is template file

```
<h2>Webhooks</h2>

<% if @webhooks.present? %>
  <ul>
    <% @webhooks.each do |webhook| %>
      <li><%= webhook.topic %> : <%= webhook.address %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
<% else %>
  <p>This app has not created any webhooks for this Shop. Add webhooks to your ShopifyApp initializer if you need webhooks</p>
<% end %>
```

This is what's displayed in my app
[image]

So what am I missing? any help!

Comment: Did you add those webhooks after you installed the app? If so you gonna have to uninstall it and re-install it again. Or you can create them using the API.

Comment: I added new webhook from `Settings -> Notifications -> Create new webhook`. I tried to reinstall many time but same issue. `add those webhooks after you installed the app`: Where is this,  Karim Tarek?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When the OAuth callback is completed successfully, ShopifyApp will queue a background job which will ensure all the specified webhooks exist for that shop  ([Reference](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_app#webhooksmanager)).

Do you have [sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) or something similar running in the background? If not make sure you set something up, that's probably what you need.

You may read more about Rails Active Job [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html).